# Macbook Air (2011) WIFI Issue

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro

After working perfectly for the past 1.5 years I have had my 13" MBA, I suddenly had WIFI issues. Let me give a few details about my experience:

I suddenly had issues connecting to the internet (I was able to connect to the wifi, but could not load a webpage in less than 2-3 minutes if/when it loaded) at my home, but had no issues when connecting directly to my modem via an ethernet cable - thus, it was not a network card issue or an issue with my internet provider.

After that, I had suddenly begun having issues connecting to the networks at my office and school...which is when I began to get frustrated.

See my answer below for how I resolved this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having issues with my home, office, and school networks (i.e. all networks I tried connecting to), I realized that the only thing these networks all had in common (besides my computer) was that they were all secured networks.

When I tried connecting to an open network, I had no issues at all - thus my realization that some settings on my MBA got screwed up somehow, and the security authorization was screwing things up.

Resolution: To do a hard reset on your WIFI settings, go into Macintosh HD -> Library -> Preferences (see screenshot below). Remove the SystemConfiguration  folder (place it on your Desktop for now). Reboot your MBA.

At this point, I had no issues connecting to any WIFI networks - I hope you have the same result.

[image]

Comment: Removing the whole SystemConfiguration folder is a bit heavy... Just remove the files that you needed to remove. You are "resetting" more than you need/should.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the whole SystemConfiguration folder, just do the following:

> 1. Turn your Wi-Fi off
> 2. Open Finder window
> 3. Press Command+Shift+G
> 4. Enter "/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/" and hit enter
> 5. Delete the following files (
>      **com.apple.airport.preferences.plist**,
>      **com.apple.network.identification.plist**,
>      **NetworkInterfaces.plist**,
>      **preferences.plist**)
> 6. Empty the trash
> 7. Reboot your Mac
> 8. Turn Wi-Fi back on again